# How to reload an angular controller with the updated $scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My problem is I need **"det" value** applied to the controller and reload it. 
Anyway nevermind it and continue reading first so you will understand my question.

I have this controller below.
At first load, the xxx isn't going to exist in the object then det value will be null. So it is  expected that the controller's service will have an error telling that it can't be find. *(See Controller code below)*

However, when I click a button on my page (buttons html code is not here, I don't think it is necessary), it fills the object in and I'm wishing to reload the controller so I will see my expected output.

The HTML below is the one who loads the controller, what I'm expecting is that the
**data-ng-model="{{$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx}}"** will update the xxx value in controller. And it actually does because I'm using **"<*span>{{$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].detnumber}}<*/span>"** to test it.

Now, again,
My problem is I need the **"det" value** applied to the controller and reload it.
What I'm thinking is to create a new controller but I will just repeat the code.

---

**//html**

```
<div data-ng-switch-when="thisIsIt" ControllerOne data-ng-model="{{$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx}}"></div>
<span>{{$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx}}</span>
```

---

**//Attribute ControllerOne**

```
controller: function ($scope, $element, $http) {

    function par() {               
       var xxx= null;
       xxx = $scope.$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx;
       var det = { xxx: xxx};              
       return det;
    }


$http.post('/api/values/entries/GoHere', par()).success(function (salData) {

     var buildSHGraph = function (shData) {
        //code code codes...
     }

     $scope.Array1 = [];

     angular.forEach(salData, function (evt) {
        //Code Code Codes
     });

     buildSHGraph($scope.Array1);

});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing you can use $rootScope and pass your value to it. Then the value can be accessible globally by your application.

When your value is downloaded from ajax, the scope/html will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

When you define variable with 'var xxx' cannot access it outside of the scope of this function, in your case 'par'.

```
function par() {
    this.xxx = null;
    this.xxx = $scope.$parent.$root.ParentItems['xxx'].xxx;
}
```

When you try to change view from callback from async task such as $http.post you need to '$digest' or '$apply' the scope

```
//Do this in success callback function in your ajax request
$timeout(function() { //$timeout must be setup as dependency in constructor such as $scope and $http
    $scope.$digest();
});
```